# Migration from solo consensus to raft consensus

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I've used byfn.sh to build a hyperledger network with solo consensus.

Now I want to migrate to Raft consensus, but without destroying the blockchain and start from zero.

Is it possible to migrate Hyperledger fabric from Solo consensus to Raft consensus ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and it's basically very similar to the Kafka to Raft migration. Take a look at the [Kafka to Raft migration guide](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/kafka_raft_migration.html) and follow it

Comment: Thank you.
Excuse me if this sound like a stupid question.
So I should fire up 4 new orderers and proceed to migrate from solo to RAFT ?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you do that, every orderer that you add must be added to all channels, otherwise you're stuck.  Look at https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-17479 for more details